# Django exclude field from all queries

Tags: python, django, database-migration, django-orm, django-migrations

I am running Django on Heroku with zero-downtime feature. This means that during deployment there are two version of code running (old and new) on the same database. That's why we need to avoid any backward incompatible migrations.

It there a possibility to exclude a field from Django query on a given model?

Let say we have a model (version 1):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.TextField()
```

In some time in the future we want to move address to the separate table. We know that we should not delete a field for older code to work so Person model may look like (version 2):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    _address = models.TextField(db_name='address')
```

This way if old code will query for address it will get it from Person table even if database has been migrated (it will be an old value, but let assume thats not a big issue).

How now I can safetly delete `_address` field? If we will deploy version 3 with `_address` field deleted then code for version 2 will still try to fetch `_address` on select, even if it's not used anywhere and will fail with "No such column" exception.

Is there a way to prevent this and mark some field as "non-fetchable" within the code for version 2? So version 2 will not delete field, but will not fetch it anymore and version 3 will delete field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use custom object manager for `defer` your specific field/fields for all the queryset.

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CustomManager, self).get_queryset().defer('_address',)
```

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    _address = models.TextField(db_name='address')

    objects = CustomManager()
```

after that in your any queryset against `Person` model will not include `_address` field in query by default.

Comment: Consider: When calling save() for instances with deferred fields, only the loaded fields will be saved. See save() for more details.

Comment: when you create new instance with save() provided deferred fields, all fields will be saved as expected. but after save() the objects can not retrieve the updated deferred fields because of defer(). If you query later then you will get the expected results. Thank you

Comment: Thats sound fine, as fields which I want to defer are the ones which I want not to use anymore, but not delete from db yet, until "version - 1" is not using them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it:

### QuerySet.defer():

*"In some complex data-modeling situations, your models might contain a lot of fields, some of which could contain a lot of data (for example, text fields), or require expensive processing to convert them to Python objects. If you are using the results of a queryset in some situation where you don’t know if you need those particular fields when you initially fetch the data, you can tell Django not to retrieve them from the database."* - [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer)

`Entry.objects.defer("headline", "body")`

**OR**

With django 1.8 onwards: use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). You can only include fields that you want. You can also use [`Queryset.only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) and [`Queryset.defer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) to refine your queryset queries. You can chain `defer()` calls as well

`Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'headline')`

Comment: That's not quite what I need - this will need to go on every queryset querying this model. Or can I somehow add "deffered" queryset as default one?